# Data Validation for Unique Record and Specific Digit length

Tags: excel

I want to apply Data Validation on a cell. When a user enter a numeric value data validation should check its length 13 digits. If the length is greater than or less than 13 digits then message should be shows "Please enter 13 digit value" or do not accept the value. If the length is equal to 13 digits then the formula check duplicates within the range. If duplicate record found then a message should be shows "Please Enter Unique Records Only".

I am using this formula but it would not working properly...

=IF(LEN(A:A)=13,IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)>1,"duplicate",IF(LEN(A:A)<>13,"Please enter 13 digit","Please enter 13 digit")))

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: A:A? Is there a cell as such?

Comment: First thing don't use , use | (pipe), second your conditions don't add up to desired result. why print "Please enter 13 digit" twice

Comment: Couldnt you use the built in data validation tool?

Answer (score 1):

This cleaned-up version of your formula would do what you want, I think, if entered in B1 and copied down. It only marks duplicates for the second occurrence onward:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)=13,IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)>1,"duplicate",),"Please enter 13 digit")
```

For Data Validation, I think the best you can do is combine the two conditions, like:

```
=AND(LEN(A1)=13,COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)=1)
```

and use an Error Message like, "Please enter a 13-digit, non-duplicated value"

Comment: Fwiw, the OPs `Len(A:A)` is valid.  It's called [implicit intersection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20941667/445425)

Comment: @chrisneilsen, interesting point. Generally, I'd only use that if I had a reason, otherwise it's hard to understand. Specifically, in brief testing for Data Validation, it seems to just refer to the value in A1. I tested in both directions, i.e., invalid data in A2 isn't validated, but invalid data in A1 causes A2 validation error even if A2 is valid. BTW, what did you think of my answer in general?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming A2 is the cell where value is entered, B2:B4 is the range of values and the value entered is whole number, Use this :

```
=IF(LEN(A2)<>13|"Not 13 Digits"|IF(COUNTIF(B2:B4|A2)>1|"DUPLICATE"|A2))
```

Comment: tell me if it's helpful or not. If it is do mark it as answer. Greedy ME :P

Comment: Why the pipe symbol? In the US it's commas, and in some other regions it's semicolons, but I haven't seen pipes before. I don't think you should assume that's the case for the OP.

Comment: Oh, may be that is the case. I haven't used excel much. When I used ',' Formula error occurred. The tooltip showed me Pipes so I used and suggested them. My bad.